# Border background of label wrapping individual letters

Tags: qgis, labeling, line, borders, background

Using Qgis 3.28.14

I am trying to visualize labels with a background and setting the border of the background.

The result I am having is wrapping each letter instead of the entire label

[image]

How do I get to have the outline for the entire label?

Edit:

relevant settings

Background:
rectangle
buffer
simple fill with outline

Placement:
curved
allowed position: Left of line, on line, Line orientation dependent position
Label overrun set very high

Comment: Please provide your full label settings.

Comment: @Erik full label settings is pretty vast. What exactly do you need to know?

Comment: Maybe sharing a sample dataset could help - even with dummy data if you don't want to reveal actual data.

Comment: it is easy to reproduce. a line label with background and outline set to curved placement...but I think, there is no solution, only to set it to "parallel" or "horizontal" line placement

Comment: @eurojam, yes, you got the settings right, I just added them, and setting the placement to parallel does the trick. It is the solution I needed if you want to post it. A curved placement was not necessary here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the line label placement mode is set to "curved" it looks this:

[image]

setting it to "parallel" - if possible -  would avoid that

[image]

Comment: So then the curved style can be considered a bug?

Comment: I don't think it's a bug, because it's not easy to make a single rectangle around curved labels - IMO technically the label is splitted into several letters...